# How to specify categorical variable order with pandas pyplot

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a chart for the mean values of a variable base on the day of the week. I was able to get the data plotted but is ordered as Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday.

I would like the days of the week to start on Monday and continue with Tuesday, etc. (Trying to plot the data before I have all of the days of the week, not sure if that makes a difference or not)

Here is my code

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    file = 'new_RescueTime.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df2 = df[['TotalTime','Day_week']]
    df_dow = df2.groupby('Day_week').mean()

    df_dow.plot.bar(legend = False, rot = 60)
    plt.title('Total minutes by day of week')
    plt.xlabel('Day of Week')
    plt.ylabel('Minutes')```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYEJ3.png
````

Comment: Specifically for `groupby` - [Sort by certain order (Situation: pandas DataFrame Groupby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275294/sort-by-certain-order-situation-pandas-dataframe-groupby) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You van try using an Ordered Category:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dow = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'dow': [np.random.choice(dow) for _ in range(n)],
                   'value': [np.random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(n)]})
df['dow'] = pd.Categorical(df['dow'], ordered=True, categories=dow)
df.groupby(by='dow').mean().plot(kind='bar')
```

Result:

[image]